# About PhoneGap JS Engine and iOS native components

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

How PhoneGap JS Engine and iOS native components call each other?
I found all them pointing to a class called PGPlugin,and declare in PhoneGap.plist.
But when I new a empty project and drag file from PhoneGapLib to project,the function onDeviceReady doesn't work.
I want to know how PhoneGap works.
Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking.

Perhaps the PhoneGap wiki ( http://wiki.phonegap.com/ ) or the PhoneGap API docs could help you ( http://docs.phonegap.com/ ).

If you are asking specifically about how the plugin architecture works (i.e.: being able to interface with custom native code via JavaScript) then this is a basic description and some documentation on writing your own:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins

And heaps of examples at the phone gap plugins repo on GitHub:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins